# How to cancel scheduled local notification (on iPhone) through the app extension (iWatch)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications

I would like to cancel repeating local notification that has been scheduled in main app target (iPhone), through the app extension (iWatch - watchOS). When I try to cancel it like: UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests() in iWatch extension, it has no effect on requests made by main target. Is it possible to be done somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this would be possible if iPhone and Watch apps have 'shared' instance of UNUserNotificationCenter. But they don't. Each target has separate instance, so you can not cancel local scheduled user notifications that has been scheduled from other device.

You can read more details about user notifications and all the abilities in: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2018/02/notification-handling-on-watchkit/, blog by Eric Blair, lead engineer of MartianCraft